# second monitor detected but screen is black

Tags: 22.04, monitor, displayport

I have Ubuntu 22.04, a GeForce 3080 with an ASUS VE278 and an ASUS VE276. Both monitors are connected with DisplayPort cables. If I run this:

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*DP-1 1920/598x1080/336+0+0  DP-1
 1: +DP-2 1920/598x1080/336+1920+0  DP-2
```

it sees my seconds monitor, but it is just a black screen. The power LED is amber. If I try to turn it on I get the ASUS logo for a fraction of a second and the power LED is blue. Then a box says "DVI NO SIGNAL". Then it goes away and the LED goes to amber and the screen goes black.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out the key problem was the "DVI NO SIGNAL". I have another computer plugged into it using the DVI port. It forced me to switch over to that computer and then I could get to the monitor's on screen menu to change the input. It would be nice if the monitor would let me change the input regardless of what the active port is.